# Detecting right clicks in Rebol

Tags: rebol, rebol2

```
view layout [
  box red feel [
    engage: func [face action event] [
      if action = 'alt-down [print "alt down"] ; 1
      if event/double-click [print "double-click"] ; 2
    ]
  ]
]
```

This code doesn't detect double right clicks.
When I quickly double click right button it will detect only 1 click (line 1).
I've tried detecting double-clicks but it doesn't work on right mouse button (line 2).

Is there a way to detect successive right mouse button clicks?